# Huion Tablet Invisible "No-Draw Zone"

Tags: graphics-tablet

So I got my new Huion Tablet not too long ago, and I was very excited to use it. Now I normally use Firealpaca to draw, and when I used my tablet, I noticed a strange invisible circle around the original point of contact between the pen and the tablet where I can not draw. The only way I can get rid of it is by leaving this zone around the original point of contact. Once my cursor leaves that zone, It will let me draw anywhere, even where the zone was. This will also happen every time my pen touches the tablet, and no matter what I do I can not seem to get it to go away. I tried using it with SAI Paint Tool after and once again, I could not draw around the point of contact. However, this did not happen when I tested it in Microsoft paint.

Comment: Sounds like a deadzone feature in those applications that allows you to align your pen correctly before it'll start drawing lines. I imagine MSPaint is not clever enough for this though.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps and determine if this helps: open your huion pen display control panel and uncheck the box labeled "Support Tablet PC" and apply. Close the application, and unplug the display from USB. Then, after plugging the display back in - open the control panel and enable "Support Tablet PC" and press apply.

You should have full control once again.